# Response might change which causes the data structure defined to throw error

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a GrammarSentence class inheriting the BaseModel and defines the structure of my api response. However if the response is none, the structure changes, which throws an error. How can i edit the structure so that this can be solved.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
class GrammarSentence(BaseModel):
  """
  Model for the response containing a list of sentences with grammar mistake.
  """
  corrected_sentences: list[dict[str, str]]
```

This is the class and the response would be

```json
{'corrected_sentences': {"sentence":"grammar_issue_solved_sentece"}
```

However if none of the sentences are having any issues then it would return `{'corrected_sentences': [None]}`

I added in `{'corrected_sentences': [{"": ""}]}` to return, if there are no sentences with grammar issue. However I want to see if i can edit the model itself so that it can also be accomodated.

Comment: can you please provide code block?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From a user standpoint it would be more clear if you returned an empty list - instead of a List with a None element in it, which would have to special cased every time: `{'corrected_sentences': [None]}` vs `{'corrected_sentences': []}` - in the last case it's clear that there wasn't any sentences to correct, in the first case it seems like the first sentence was `None` for some reason.

Comment: As MatsLindh says, just edit the field `corrected_sentences: list[dict[str, str]] = Field(default_factory=[])`, where Field is from Pydantic. This would be easier to understand in frontend and user standpoint.